# ReasonML: Unclosed "("

Tags: reason

```
if(1<Array.length(Node.Process.argv)) {
    Js.log("Too many arguments!");
}
```

The above 3-line ReasonML program does not compile:

> Error: Unclosed "(" (opened line 1, column 2)

Tongue-in-cheek question: what is wrong? This is my pet peeve about ReasonML, because I counted parentheses and they do match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you need to insert a space after the `<`. As for the details of why this happens, I'm asking on Discord. I assume it has something to do with JSX.